# TabLayout в Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-tablayout, fragment-transaction

В моем приложении в активити есть BottomNavigationView через которое открываются фрагменты. У меня есть два фрагмента с TabLayout(сотрудники, сообщения). При нажатии на сотрудников все работает, потом при нажатии на сообщения TabLayout продолжает работать, но если вновь открыть сообщения, то TabLayout багается, ничего не показывает. Я так полагаю, что ошибка кроется в моем .replace, где создаются просто новые фрагменты. Как открыть фрагмент из backStack, или как это вообще нужно реализовать?

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.navigation_messages:
            if(fm.findFragmentByTag(MessagesFragment.TAG) == null) {
                fm.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_container_main, new MessagesFragment(),
                                MessagesFragment.TAG)
                        .addToBackStack(MessagesFragment.TAG)
                        .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                        .commit();
            } // Как снова показать фрагмент из backStack?
            return true;
        case R.id.navigation_events:
            Toast.makeText(this,menuItem.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.navigation_mailing_lists:
            Toast.makeText(this,menuItem.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.navigation_employees:
            if(fm.findFragmentByTag(UsersFragment.TAG) == null) {
                fm.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_container_main, new UsersFragment(),
                                UsersFragment.TAG)
                        .addToBackStack(UsersFragment.TAG)
                        .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                        .commit();
            } // Как снова показать фрагмент из backStack?
            return true;

        case R.id.navigation_menu:
            Toast.makeText(this,menuItem.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Да и плюс ко всему читал, что фрагменты во фрагментах не есть гуд.

PS: Имеет ли смысл в таких ситуациях использовать фрагменты? Или же лучше работать с несколькими активити для каждого элемента меню

UPD:
Код фрагмента сообщений:

```
public class MessagesFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String TAG = MessagesFragment.class
        .getSimpleName();
private View mRootView;
private FloatingActionButton mNewMessageButton;
private TabLayout mTabLayout;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private MessagesPagerAdapter mAdapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false);

    mTabLayout = mRootView.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_messages);
    mViewPager = mRootView.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_messages);
    mNewMessageButton = mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fab_new_message);

    mAdapter = new MessagesPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    mAdapter.addFragment(new MessagesInboxFragment(), "Входящие");
    mAdapter.addFragment(new MessagesOutboxFragment(), "Исходящие");

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    mNewMessageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(mRootView.getContext(), NewMessageActivity.class));
        }
    });

    return mRootView;
}
}
```

Адаптер:

```
public class MessagesPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private List<Fragment> mFragmentsMessages = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> mFragmentsMessagesTitles = new ArrayList<>();

public MessagesPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    return mFragmentsMessages.get(i);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentsMessages.size();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentsMessagesTitles.get(position);
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentsMessages.add(fragment);
    mFragmentsMessagesTitles.add(title);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TabLayout ничем не мешает при нормальной реализации. Но, я бы для начала код привел в порядок, как минимум.
Хотя я привду не идеальный вариант, но попробуйте сделать примерно так:

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity implements
    BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private Fragment mFirstFragment = new FirstFragment();
private Fragment mSecondFragment = new SecondFragment();




    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        loadFragment(mFirstFragment);
    }
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

 @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    if (bottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId() != menuItem.getItemId()) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_main:
                fragment = mFirstFragment;
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_taxi:
               fragment = mFirstFragment;
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_bus:
                fragment = mSecondFragment;
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_train:
                fragment = mSecondFragment;
                break;
        }
    }
    return loadFragment(fragment);
}

 private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if (fragment != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.contentLayout, fragment)
                .commit();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int selectedItemId = bottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId();
    if (R.id.navigation_main != selectedItemId) {
        loadFragment(mFirstFragment);
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_main);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Это все хорошо, но это не есть решение моей проблемы ведь

Comment: Нет никакой по сути разницы фрагменты или активити в смысле вывода на экране. У вас проблема в коде адаптера или еще где то.  покажите код ViewPagera и фрагментов

Comment: Я обновил вопрос